# Align dynamically generated divs

Tags: html, css

We have a widget that is returning some results in the form of a div containing n number of divs. Currently they are one on top of the other in the usual div display. Is there a way to make them side by side like 2x2 on each row?

```
<div class="container-div">
 <div class="result">result1</div>
 <div class="result">result2</div>
 <div class="result">result3</div>
 <div class="result">result4</div>
</div>
```

Currently they display the result divs on top of one another, can we have them display 2 per row (based on width)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The below answer works! Thanks for that! I had attempted inline-block on the results, but that caused some funky display. These results are sitting in an overlay and the spacing was off due to limited pixels using inline-block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach using [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout):

```
.container-div{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.result{
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```css
.container-div{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.result{
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-div">
 <div class="result">result1</div>
 <div class="result">result2</div>
 <div class="result">result3</div>
 <div class="result">result4</div>
</div>
```

if you want to get more "results" per row, amend the percentage from 50% accordingly: 100%/n

Comment: Be aware of smaller viewports because they will display the items 1 per row when they have not enough space